# How to dynamically change border color in next js with tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to change the border color of my email input dynamically in the state of valid or invalid email id. I have written the following method but it is not working as expected , as we can say it is not working at all . Any workaround to do that .

```
import { useState } from 'react'; 
import Image from 'next/image';

const NavItem = props =>(
    <li>
      <a className="text-md font-bold text-gray-700 px-2 py-1 hover:bg-gray-300 rounded transition-colors duration-300" href={props.href}>{props.text}</a>
    </li>
  );

export default function Post() {
  const [validEmail,setvalidEmail] = useState(true);

  return (
      <div>
           <nav className="flex justify-between p-4" >
      <div className="">
      <Image
      src="/media/logonew.png"
      alt="logo"
      width={180}
      height={40}
      />
      </div>
      <div>
      <ul className="flex space-x-3 py-2 px-3">
      <NavItem  href="/" text="Home"/>
          <NavItem  href="/products" text="Products"/>
          <NavItem href="/eligibility" text="Eligibility"/>
          <NavItem href="/login" text="Login"/>
          <NavItem href="/faq" text="FAQ"/>
        </ul>
      </div>
        
      </nav>

      <div className="conatiner mx-auto max-w-xl mt-10">
        <div className="text-center md:flex md:text-left  shadow-sm">
            <div className="border text-center p-5 rounded-xl">
                <h2 className="text-6xl text-blue-600 m-5 font-semibold">Register</h2>
                <form onSubmit={()=>{}} className="text-left">
                    <p className="text-blue-600 font-semibold">Email</p>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email id" className="bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border validEmail?focus:border-blue-600:border-red-600 my-2 w-full"/>
                    <p className="text-blue-600 font-semibold">Password</p>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" className="bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border focus:border-blue-600  my-2 w-full"/>
                    <p className="text-blue-600 font-semibold">Confirm Password</p>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm your password" className="bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border focus:border-blue-600  my-2 w-full"/>
                    <p className="text-blue-600 font-semibold">Full name</p>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name" className="bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border focus:border-blue-600  my-2 w-full"/>
                    <p className="text-blue-600 font-semibold">Date of birth</p>
                    <input type="date" placeholder="Enter your password" className="bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border focus:border-blue-600  my-2 w-full"/>
                    <p className="text-blue-600 font-semibold">Organization Name <span className="text-gray-500">*Optional</span></p>
                    <input type="Text" placeholder="Enter your password" className="bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border focus:border-blue-600  my-2 w-full"/>

                    <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-600 text-white p-3 rounded my-3 font-bold text-xl w-full">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find that you are trying to change your className value here :
`<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email id" className="bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border validEmail?focus:border-blue-600:border-red-600 my-2 w-full"/>`

With conditional operator you can achieve this with something like this :

```html
function post() {
  const [validEmail,setvalidEmail] = useState(true);
  const validEmailClass = "bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border focus:border-blue-600 my-2 w-full";
  const invalidEmailClass = "bg-white rounded border border-gray-300 p-3 focus:border border-red-600 my-2 w-full";
 

return (
  ...
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email id" className={validEmail ?  validEmailClass : invalidEmailClass}/>
  ...
);
}
```

Comment: You can use conditional in string. Why would you make 2 variables which are like almost same if you can change just one class?

Comment: @Jax-p Man I was juste showing that conditions won't work in literal strings, your approach is good also. Now he can implement in his code as he likes ! I juste find my approach more readable

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you wrote condition inside of a string as a string.

```js
// you have
className="... validEmail?focus:border-blue-600:border-red-600 ..."

// should be
className=`... ${ validEmail ? 'focus:border-blue-600' : 'border-red-600' } ...`
```

JavaScript is not being evaluated inside of common strings (`"`,`'`). How it could know if `:` is part of conditional or part of your class name? You have to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#template_literals) as is mentioned above.

---

If you don't want to use template literals you can do it in good old way with string concatination `+`:

```js
className={"..." + validEmail ? "focus:border-blue-600" : "border-red-600" + "..."}
```

---

For more complex solutions take a look on [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) library.